# Gas fees differ for updating different values?

Tags: gas, mapping, gas-price, uint256

I've did some gas efficiency tests on the testnet and wonder why the following is the case...

Updating values can be done with both of these methods:

x += y; /// or /// x = x + y;

For mappings, like user balances, the first example is the more cost efficient one:

_balances[holder] += 10;....................................................(212.601 deployment; 27.973 calling function)

_balances[holder] = _balances[holder] + 10;..............(215.829 deployment; 28.835 calling function)

However, for stored values (uint256) it's the other way round:

number = number + 10;.....................................................(206.331 deployment; 27.067 calling function)

number += 10;.......................................................................(207.843 deployment; 27.086 calling function)

Can anyone tell me why one is cheaper than the other in general, or why the cheaper method for mappings is the more expensive option on regular stored values?